# Getting an error "bad recv() len: 53888928" from mongodb when trying to bulk insert around 300,000 items

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I tried to bulk insert more than 250,000 items I got an error from the server saying:
"Wed Mar 10 21:37:34 bad recv() len: 53888928
Wed Mar 10 21:37:34 end connection 127.0.0.1:2795"
I did not find any data on that issue on google that is useful to me.

These are the results for my machine using single threaded approach with one open connection (intel core2duo , 2.66GHz , 3.25GB Ram, win xp sp2, standard single HD)

Anyone?

thanks :)

Comment: you might be better off asking for help on their mailing list.

Comment: Do you have win 32 or win 64? On win 32 the max db size limit is 2 gigabyte. Maybe you ran into this limit?

Comment: Probably hitting the limit size - what language / driver are you using? Try chunking up the bulk insert.